# ExtendScript get index number from searched Comp result

Tags: javascript, arrays, extendscript

I've got this code that is sorting through the various items in after effects and returning all the compositions in the project, then I narrow it down based on the specific composition i'm looking for, in this case one ending with assemble. I get the name and that's great but what I really need is the index number to come along with the name, so that when I search for assemble I get a return of app.project.item(3), its index in the project window. Every time I try to get the number from the array all I seem to get is the total number of items which doesn't help.

Thanks.

```
function retrieveProjectItems(itemType){
var typeOptions = ["Composition", "Folder", "Footage"];
for(var t = 0; t<3; t++){
    if(itemType == typeOptions[t]){
        var proj, itemTotal, curItem, itemArray;
        itemAry = [];
        proj = app.project;
        itemTotal = proj.numItems;
        for(var i = 1; i <= itemTotal; i++){
            curItem = proj.item(i);

            //alert(curItem.name);


            if(curItem.typeName == itemType){
                itemAry[itemAry.length] = curItem.name;
                }
            }
        return itemAry;

        }
    }
}
retrieveProjectItems("Composition");
//alert(comps); lists all COMPS in the Array

var comps = itemAry;
var compWithAssemble;
for(var i in comps){
if(comps[i].indexOf("assemble") > -1){ ///search for part of the name///////////////////////////////////
    compWithAssemble = comps[i];

    break;
}
}
// compWithAssemble has the string you are looking for.
alert(compWithAssemble);
//app.project.item(3).selected = true;
compWithAssemble.selected = true; //I'm looking to make this work...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to programatically find the composition with a layer named `"assemble"`

This bit of code

```
if(comps[i].indexOf("assemble") > -1){ ///search for part of the name///////////////////////////////////
    compWithAssemble = comps[i];

    break;
}
```

does not give you the results you want because `comps[i]` is a object of CompItem, not an Array or a collection.  You need to first retrieve the Layer Collection for each `comp[i]`.  Then, when you have that LayerCollection, you can find the layer named `"assemble"` by using the .byName() method.  If you don't get a returned layer, you'll receive `null`, otherwise, you'll receive a Layer Object.

It might look something like:

```
var comps = itemAry;
var compWithAssemble;

for (var i in comps){
    if(comps[i].layers.byName("assemble") != null) {
       compWithAssemble = comps[i];
       break;
    }
}
```